# Iterate through Json objects in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Having trouble rendering json on an Angular 2 app.  Tried a few suggestions and I've gotten to the code below.  Issue is, I can see it in my console log, but can't see it on my template. No errors are popping up either.

API:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "perk": "apple equipment",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "perk": "catered food",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

API service:

```
 getPerkList() {
   return this.http.get(this.perkUrl).map(
    (res) => res.json()
   )
 }
```

component.ts:

```
export class CompanyProfileEditComponent implements OnInit {
  perkList: Object;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.ApiService.getPerkList()
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.perkList = data;
     console.log(this.perkList);
 });
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul *ngIf="perkList">
  <a *ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.children |  slice:0:7" (click)="onAddPerk(perkResult)">
         <li>{{ perkResult }}</li>
  </a> 
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.children` should be `*ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.results` since the object doesn't have a property `children`, and you'll want to show a property, not the whole object in the `li`

```
 <ul *ngIf="perkList">
  <a *ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.results |  slice:0:7" (click)="onAddPerk(perkResult)">
         <li>{{ perkResult.perk }}</li>
  </a> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: Got it. That works now. I guess I was confusing myself with all the other examples I was looking at.